# Call Apex Method in <apex:repeat> to process value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a method `getCodeToDescription()` in my controller for converting the `item.Service.Code` values into another format, and I want to pass these `item.Service.Code` values into that function with every iteration and render those return values on the page. How can that be done?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!rates.RateResponse.RatedShipment}" var="item" id="theRepeat">
   <apex:outputText value="{!item.Service.Code}" id="serviceCode"/><br/>
   <apex:outputText value="{!'$'+item.TotalCharges.MonetaryValue}" id="monetaryValue"/><br/>
   <apex:outputText value="{!item.GuaranteedDelivery.BusinessDaysInTransit}" id="guarenteedDelivery"/><br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Can you share the apex method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead format that code in apex before page loads, put it into a wrappers of `rates.RateResponse.RatedShipment` and `anotherformat` then you can iterate over it.

pseudo code

```
// create wrapper
class Wrapper{
 YourDataType RatedShipment;
 YourDataType anotherformat ;

}
...
// put values into wrapper
List<Wrapper> wraperList = new List<Wrapper>; // must be public and exposed to vf
for(List<YourDataType for RatedShipment> rs: rates.RateResponse.RatedShipment){
 Wraper w = new Wrapper();
 w.RatedShipment = rs;
 w.anotherformat = getCodeToDescription(rs.Service.Code);
 wraperList.add(w);
}
...
```

on page

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wraperList}" var="wraper" id="theRepeat">
   <apex:outputText value="{!wraper.anotherformat}" id="serviceCode"/><br/>
   <apex:outputText value="{!'$'+wraper.RatedShipment .TotalCharges.MonetaryValue}" id="monetaryValue"/><br/>
   <apex:outputText value="{!wraper.RatedShipment .GuaranteedDelivery.BusinessDaysInTransit}" id="guarenteedDelivery"/><br/>
</apex:repeat>
```